# Schreibung von (Klammer-)Ergänzungen

Tags: compound, typography

Ich habe meine Zweifel über die "einzig wahre" Schreibweise im Zusammenhang mit wortergänzenden Klammern, zumal ich in freier Wildbahn schon allen Varianten begegnet bin. Sollte man beispielsweise (in der Bedeutung "Geschäft oder Hauptgeschäft")

1. (Haupt)Geschäft
2. (Haupt-)Geschäft
3. (Haupt-) Geschäft
4. (Haupt)geschäft     (Variante ergänzt nach Feedback in Kommentaren und Antworten)

schreiben? Mein persönlicher Favorit ist Variante 2, vornehmlich mit der Begründung, dass das ersatzlose Streichen der Klammern (für Programmierer: `s/[\(\)]//g`) etwas Sinnvolles übrig lässt, nämlich *Haupt-Geschäft* (und nicht etwa *HauptGeschäft* oder *Haupt- Geschäft*).
Angesichts meiner Argumentation stellt sich für Adjektive die Frage allerdings erneut: Soll man für "wahr oder halbwahr"

1. (halb)wahr
2. (halb-)wahr
3. (halb-) wahr

schreiben? 
Variante 2, damit schriftbildliche Einheitlichkeit zur Situation bei Substantiven besteht? Oder Variante 1, weil mit meiner oben gegebenen Argumentation durch Entfernen der Klammern wundeschön *halbwahr* entsteht?

[Im Nachhinein: Hier böte sich vielleicht sogar "(halb) wahr" an, passend zu "wahr oder halb wahr"; vielleicht denke man sich die Beispiele eher mit etwas definitiv zusammen zu Schreibendem wie "vorsichtig oder übervorsichtig", also "(über)vorsichtig" vs. "(über-)vorsichtig" vs. "(über-) vorsichtig"]

Comment: Schöne Frage. Ich halte auf jeden Fall ein Leerzeichen hinter der Klammer für falsch. Das würde mich sehr irritieren. Und ich bin mir sehr sicher, dass bei präfingierten Adjektiven "ohne alles" usus ist.... also "(über)vorsichtig. Bei Substantiven bin ich mal gespannt, ich tendiere aber zu "(Haupt-)Geschäft", da man auch "Haupt- und Nebenzeit" schreiben würde. Das widerspricht zwar den Adjektiven aber was soll's

Comment: Für den ersten Fall wäre noch *(Haupt)geschäft* denkbar.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Richtig, müsste ich noch aufführen, gefällt mir aber nicht weil bei völliger Streichung des Klammerteils (für Programmierer wieder `s/\(.*\)//`) der Unsinn "geschäft" herauskommt.

Comment: Abweichend zu Emanuel halte ich die Leerstelle nach der Klammer geboten, habe ich doch gelernt, dass hinter jedem Satzzeichen eine Leerstelle folgt, außer bei Klammern u. Anführungsstrichen, da werden die Leerstellen immer außen gesetzt, sowie bei aggregierten Satzzeichen - da keine Leerstellen zwischen den Satzzeichen.

Comment: @userunknown: Das, was Du gelernt hast, ist aber eher eine Zusammenfassung von Regeln, die Klammern innerhalb von Wörtern gar nicht zulassen, als ein Grundprinzip der deutschen Rechtschreibung. Mal abgesehen davon, dass die Klammer genausowenig ein Satzzeichen ist wie ein Bindestrich. Außerdem verstößt selbst das offizielle Rechtschreibregelwerk dagegen (z. B. in § 62).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Leerst. sind ja weniger eine Frage der Rechtschreibung als des Setzerhandwerks, welches sich aber wohl in Software auflöst. Die Setzregeln dienen der Lesbarkeit und es sind mehr Zeichen in der Mitte dick als oben und unten. Daher lassen sich rechts der öffnenden Klammer (Beispiel) u. links der schließenden eher Buchstaben platzieren, die nicht mit der Klammer zu verschmelzen drohen - nach außen aber läßt man eher etwas Platz. Meine Regeln habe ich von einem Maschinenschreibkurs, wo es keine halben Leerschritte gab - der richtige Setzer macht es sicher nochmal anders.

Comment: @userunknown: Leerzeichen sind zumindest insofern eine Frage der Rechtschreibung, als dass sie z. B. die Grenzen von Wörtern trennen. Was die Kollision mit Buchstaben betrifft, so stand im mechanischen Satz eine Auswahl an kleinen Abständen zur Verfügung und im digitalen Satz haben zumindest gute Schriften einen sinnvollen Abstandsausgleich (Kerning) auch für diese Fälle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vielleicht nützt es ja jemandem, [was der *Duden* darüber schreibt](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/klammern-und-bindestrich):

Um zwei **Lesarten** anzubieten, »verwendet man runde Klammern und setzt innerhalb der Klammern einen Bindestrich«.

Falls der »nicht eingeklammerte Bestandteil ein Substantiv oder etwas Substantiviertes ist, wird dieser großgeschrieben«.

Beispiele:

> - eine Menge wenig überzeugender (Allerwelts-)Argumente
> - in vergleichsweise schickem (Retro-)Design
> - mit dieser (pseudo-)psychologischen Entwicklung des Hauptmotivs
> - ein (auto-)biografisches Einsprengsel

(Am Rande: Für **Auslassungen** werden eckige Klammern verwendet, da aber ohne Bindestrich und ohne Großschreibung. Etwa: »Auswechs[e]lung«; »[Nadelstreifen]anzüge«.)

[Worttrennung](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/klammern-und-bindestrich-bei-der-worttrennung): Falls so ein Wort mit zwei Lesarten getrennt werden muss, setzt man keinen zusätzlichen Bindestrich.

Beispiel:

> (Allerwelts-)
>   Argumente

Comment: Na da bin ich ja froh, dass der Duden sich i Wesentlichen nach meinem Bauchgefühl richtet :) - Hinsichtlich der Trennung liegt wahrscheinlich die größere Gefahr darin, dass unsere ach so schlauen Computer so etwas gerne automatisch  "(Allerwelts-|)Argumente" trennen, wenn man nicht aufpasst.

Answer (score 4):

**Vorweg:**

In den offiziellen Regeln konnte ich nichts hierzu finden. Demnach wäre jegliche derartige Konstruktion nicht regelkonform. Dies ergibt sogar insofern Sinn, da Klammern »Zusätze und Nachträge« einschließen (§ 85) und es sich hier eben nicht um einen Zusatz handelt, sondern zwei alternative Möglichkeiten kompakt dargestellt werden sollen. Mit anderen Worten: Der Klammerinhalt ist nötig, damit das Geschriebene korrekt ist; er ist also kein Zusatz oder Nachtrag.

Nichtsdestotrotz kenne ich viele Sachverhalte, die mit einer derartigen Konstruktion mit Abstand am leichtesten dargestellt werden; und alternative Zeichen wüsste ich auch nicht. Man sollte sich aber bewusst sein, dass man hier Klammern gewissermaßen zweckentfremdet, womit auch gewisse Grundparadigmata der Klammersetzung keinen Sinn mehr ergeben: Beispielsweise braucht die Orthografie nicht mehr sinnvoll zu sein, wenn die Klammern samt Inhalt gestrichen werden, da es der Text in diesem Fall auch nicht ist.

**Diskussion der verschiedenen Optionen**

Das Leerzeichen geht gar nicht, da dies gegen das Grundparadigma der deutschen Rechtschreibung verstieße, dass innerhalb von Worten niemals Leerzeichen stehen.

Ohne Klammern wäre der Bindestrich in diesen Fällen manchmal falsch, manchmal optional. (Für den seltenen Fall, dass er verpflichtend ist, z. B. bei Zusammensetzungen von Eigennamen, siehe unten). Insbesondere würde er nur gesetzt werden, um die Wortfugen herauszustellen, was hier bereits durch die Klammern geschieht. Daher ist der Bindestrich nicht wegen seiner selbst nötig.

Aus der bleibenden Frage der Groß- und Kleinschreibung ergeben sich folgende Möglichkeiten:

1. Man schreibt groß weiter und setzt einen Bindestrich. Vorteil: Bei Streichung der Klammern sowohl samt als auch ohne Inhalt bleibt etwas orthografisch Korrektes stehen, sofern der Bindestrich denn zulässig ist. Nachteil: Wegen der vielen Zeichen liest es sich sehr unschön.
2. Man schreibt groß weiter und setzt keinen Bindestrich. Bei Streichung der Klammern samt Inhalt bleibt nun etwas Korrektes stehen. Bei Streichung der Klammern ohne Inhalt bleibt falscher Camel-Case. Die Leseerleichterung durch den Wegfall des Bindestrichs wird m. E. durch den ungewohnten Großbuchstaben mitten im Wort wieder zunichtegemacht.
3. Man schreibt klein weiter und setzt keinen Bindestrich. Nun bleibt bei Streichung der Klammern etwas Korrektes stehen, bei Streichung samt Inhalt jedoch nicht. Dafür ist das Wort m. E. sehr gut zu lesen, da nur die Klammer mitten im Wort als ungewohntes Element verbleibt.

**Meine persönliche Empfehlung**

Von einigen Ausnahmen (s. u.) abgesehen, würde ich weder einen Bindestrich noch ein Leerzeichen setzen und nach der Klammer klein weiterschreiben, da ich es als die mit Abstand am leichtesten zu lesende Variante ansehe, da einem nichts sofort ins Auge springt, was der gewohnten Rechtschreibung zuwiderläuft. Das einzige orthografische Problem tritt bei Streichung der Klammer samt Inhalt auf – das ist aber nichts, was unser Gehirn automatisch macht, und daher springt dieses Problem nicht sofort ins Auge. Ich empfehle also:

> (Haupt)geschäft, (halb)wahr.

Einzige Ausnahme ist, wenn bei Weglassen der Klammern ohne Inhalt ein Bindestrich zwingend erforderlich wäre, z. B. bei einer Zusammensetzung von Eigennamen. Hier würde ich den Bindestrich belassen und nach der Klammer groß weiterschreiben.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, ob ich mich der Empfehlung anschließe, aber +1 für eine sorgfältig ausgearbeitete und gut begründete Antwort.